# Plotting heatmap from multi-index value counts

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas DataFrame with multiple columns, where two of them are of type bool and called `result` and `predict`.

I use the following code to get a multi-indexed series:

```py
df.value_counts()
```

Which returns:

| result | predict |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | 886 |
|  | False | 995 |
| False | True | 35 |
|  | False | 28 |

I want to be able to plot this confusion matrix using seaborn or matplotlib.

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to create a frequency table of two columns and plot a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62179830/7758804)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

ct = pd.crosstab(df['result'], df['predict'])
print(ct)

sns.heatmap(ct)
```